# Trouble submitting my form (with jQuery validation) to the same page with $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form that uses a [jQuery system](http://www.ajaxshake.com/demo/EN/296/f45e128b/jquery-validation-script-for-your-web-pages-jval.html) to verify the input. With the default way it works, if there are no errors, it will submit. I am pretty bad with JavaScript, so my question is:

**How would I go about making this submit to the same page and put the inputs in the `$_POST` variable, so it can execute the PHP code to handle the data, while having the jQuery validation working?**

What I've noticed:

- The type for the submit button must be set to `type="button"` for the validator to work
- Having the type set to button, makes the `<form>` not submittable

PHP Snippet to validate the input (see if it actually posted into the `$_POST` variable):

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    echo $username."<br>".$email."<br>".$password;
}
```

The script for the form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table border=0 id="form" style="padding:10px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Username
        </td>
        <td align=left>
            <input name="username" type="text" size="20" jVal="{valid:function (val) { if (val.length < 3) return 'Invalid Name'; else return ''; }}">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Email address
        </td>
        <td align=left>
            <input name="email" type="text" size="40" jVal="{valid:/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/, message:'Invalid Email Address'}" jValKey="{valid:/[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-@]/, cFunc:'alert', cArgs:['Email Address: '+$(this).val()]}">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Password
        </td>
        <td align=left>
            <input name="password" id="password" type="password" jVal="{valid:function (val) { if (val.length < 4) return false; else return true; }, message:'Password of 4 or more characters required'}">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-right:20px;">
            Verify password
        </td>
        <td align=left>
            <input name="passwordconfirm" id="passwordVerify" type="password" jVal="{valid:function (val) { if ( val != eval('$(\'#password\').val()') ) return false; else return true; }, message:'Password and Verify Password Must Match'}">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="antispam" value="banana" />
            <script>
            var antiSpam = function() {
                if (document.getElementById("antiSpam")) {
                        a = document.getElementById("antiSpam");
                        if (isNaN(a.value) == true) {
                                a.value = 0;
                        } else {
                                a.value = parseInt(a.value) + 1;
                        }
                }
                setTimeout("antiSpam()", 1000);
            }
            antiSpam();
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input id="submitButton" type="button" value="Click here to register!" onClick="if ( $('#form').jVal({style:'blank',padding:8,border:0,wrap:false}) ){ this.form.submit;}">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

[If needed, the files corresponding to the jVal system (validation) can be found here, but they are most likely not needed.](http://www.ajaxshake.com/demo/EN/296/f45e128b/jquery-validation-script-for-your-web-pages-jval.html)

Thanks ahead

PS. Please do not go saying to "narrow down the problem", when I had it narrowed down and posted the specific code snippets, I was told to post the entire code, so here it is.

Comment: You looked at that website and thought “this is a good place to get JavaScript”? Drop it entirely. It is horrible. Then your problems will mostly be solved. Also, don’t write `== true`, and don’t pass strings to `setTimeout`, please.

Comment: No, I searched for a lightweight JavaScript validation system. As said in the post, I am not good with JavaScript, so I have no idea where I would make this myself. Now I have trouble implementing this into my existing user's system that is completely PHP and SQL. If you want me to drop it, then how would I go about adding a JavaScript validator?

Answer (score 0):

> How would I go about making this submit to the same page and put the
>   inputs in the $_POST variable, so it can execute the PHP code to
>   handle the data, while having the jQuery validation working?

You can post to the same page using PHP_SELF. Move the id from your table and add it to your form and use it to submit your form in the javascript code

```
<form id='form' action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
$('#form').submit() //instead of this.form.submit();
```

Also, instead of `isset($_POST)` you should use

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew all this. You've answer part of the question but forgot about the "while having the jQuery validation working" :P

Comment: Try moving id='form' from your table tag to the form tag

Comment: That did not change anything.

Comment: Replace this.form.submit with $('#form').submit();

Answer (score 0):

1. Use HTML5 validation and `<input>` types. Your browser can validate e-mail addresses better than you can, for example.
2. Drop the spam protection; it will prevent actual users from using your page. Use [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html).
3. Don’t use tables for layout. Please? At the very least, use CSS instead of the `align` attribute.
4. Don’t assume that everyone’s name is at least three characters long.

```
<form method="POST">
    <table border="0" id="form" style="padding: 10px;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Username
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="username" type="text" size="20" required />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Email address
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="email" type="email" size="40" required />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Password
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="password" id="password" type="password" required />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-right:20px;">
                Verify password
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="passwordconfirm" id="password-confirm" type="password" required />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <button>Click here to register!</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware you could validate forms using HTML5. I'll look into reCAPTCHA. I just used table's to set a quick layout for testing, don't worry, the real page uses div's and span's. Using this HTML5 validation, is there a way to make the input a minimum and maximum size? Also, how do I validate the password field inputs are identical, without having to refresh the page AKA only submittable when ALL input is correct? I know I can do this with PHP, but I don't want that since it will refresh the page before validating.

Comment: @BananaMan: Maximum lengths have been around before HTML5; use the `maxlength` attribute. A minimum length of 1 can be enforced using `required`, and more with the `pattern` attribute with a regular expression like `^.{2}`; minimum lengths that are not 1, however, should probably be used sparingly. The password check needs to be done with JavaScript. Make your errors work properly with PHP before adding that, though; then you can make the JavaScript match more easily.

Comment: The way I had it working using PHP was an if statement: `if(($_POST['password']) != ($_POST['passwordconfirm']))` . As mentioned, I am not very experienced with JavaScript, therefore, how would I go about matching this with JavaScript?

Comment: Grab each element with `document.getElementById('element’s ID')`, then compare their values, e.g. `if (password.value !== passwordConfirm.value)`. Two more things, though: 1) Having the page reload is okay. 2) Become more experienced with JavaScript!

Comment: To expand on that: you’re going to need *a lot* of JavaScript just to insert an error message and bind the appropriate event listeners the right way. Something else that’s often overlooked, by the way, is that *keeping the user’s password in the form after postback is okay too*. Really. Ideally, the user won’t notice the difference, save for a bit of immediacy (on blur, for example). That’s what JavaScript is for.

Comment: Thanks, I know having the page reload is okay, but I think it's fancier if you get the error without having to reload the page, just my preference :) I have been experimenting a lot with JavaScript, but I just can't seem to get the hang of it.. I've tried many things but I just don't get it :( I mean, I even know Lua... Anyway, I will play around with this and see how far I get :) Thanks!

Comment: Hmm… is there a particular part you don’t get? The core language, the DOM API, the event model, the best way to tie it into HTML…?

Comment: I am familiar with the basic's of coding, such as `if` and various loops and stuff. I know how to declare variables and how they work with array's and stuff, but just the way it works and all comes together is complicated for me. Any kind of code snippet that is not ment for learning purposes (AKA very easy) is hard for me to understand. If I would set up anything in JavaScript I wouldn't have a clue where to start.